# Laravel NotFoundHttpException for route

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.3.28, PHP 5.6.15 in XAMPP 5.6.15

In my file **routes\web.php** I add

```
Route::get('/about', 'DefaultController@about');
```

(the controller, the method and the view exists)

*php artisan route:list* return

```
    +--------+----------+------------+------+----------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI        | Name | Action                                       | Middleware   |
+--------+----------+------------+------+----------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /          |      | App\Http\Controllers\DefaultController@home  | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | about      |      | App\Http\Controllers\DefaultController@about | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user   |      | Closure                                      | api,auth:api |
+--------+----------+------------+------+----------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

and when I try to browse the Not Found Exception is raised. Looking for the error in the forum I understand that is due to an incorrect configuration of Laravel or *.htaccess* file.
I don't understand how correctly fix the problem and why in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/installation) it is not mentioned the need of this file.
Thanks to all for any kind of help or suggestions.

**UPDATE**

Here follow as requested the error message

**NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:**

```
in RouteCollection.php line 161
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 766
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 621
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 607
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 268
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 150
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 117
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Comment: Can you post the entire Laravel error you get?

Comment: did you try `/about` and are other routes working?

Comment: The file comes with laravel itself and resides in public folder. And that should be your document root. Other than that check if mod_rewrite is on

Comment: What is `routes\web.php` ? Maybe I'm mistaken, but arn't the routes in Laravel 5.3 defined In `app\Http\routes.php`

Comment: @DainisAbols Since 5.3 Laravel uses routes/web.php for web request and routes/api.php for api requests.

Comment: The htaccess in _public_ is `RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]` and I expecte/would like that the URL **mylaravel** turn into **mylaravel/public/index.php** and **mylaravel/about** turn into **mylaravel/public/index.php/about**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i wrote in comment to the original question I found the **.htaccess** file in *public* folder.
I modify the rules in this way

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteBase /mylaravel/public/          #----> ADDED THIS
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L] #----> TWO ROW
# RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]           #----> INSTEAD OF THIS

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

In this way the URLs:

- localhost/mylaravelproject/public/
- localhost/mylaravelproject/public/about
- localhost/mylaravelproject/public/orders
- localhost/mylaravelproject/public/orders/1
- ...

use the correct *route*.